# Find land parcel coordinates in Google Earth

Tags: coordinates, google-earth, land-survey

> A parcel of land (Lot 1, Blk-52 of the subdivision survey
> Psd-05-023701, being a portion of Phase 2, Psd-05-022167), situated in
> Barangay Alawihao, Municipality of Daet, Province of Camarines Norte,
> Island of Luzon. Bounded on the NW., along 5-1 by Lot 2; on the NE.,
> along line 1-2 by Lot 3, all Blk-52; on the SE., along line 2-3-4 by
> Alley 37; and on the SW., along line 4-5 by alley 36, all of
> Psd-05-023701. Beginning at a point marked “1” on the plan being N. 69
> deg. 29’ E., 1942.64 m from BLBM No. 2, Dogongan, Daet, Camarines
> Norte,  thence S. 81 deg. 45’ W., 10.00 m. to point 2; thence S. 8
> deg. 15’ W., 7.40 m. to point 3;  thence S. 53 deg. 14’ W., 3.01 m. to
> point 4; thence N. 81 deg. 45’ W., 7.88 m. to point 5; thence N. 8
> deg. 13’E., 9.52 m. to point 0f beginning,
> containing an area of NINETY THREE (93) SQUARE METERS.

> All corners
> referred to are indicated on the plan and are marked on the ground by
> P.S. cyl. conc. mons. 15 x 40 cm. Bearings: true; date of original
> survey on Feb. 7-8 1932 and that of the subdivision survey July 1-31,
> 1997 by Geodetic Engineer and was approved on Feb. 18, 1998. xxxxxxx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need a Point of Beginning. Please post both Psd-05-023701 and Psd-05-022167 Maps.